# Perl vs Sed regex substitue /(foo|bar)/

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I'm hoping someone might explain why sed does not work where perl does for this issue:

```
$ egrep "(foo|bar)=0" /var/tmp/test.txt
This is example output of the test.txt file foo=0
This is another example output of the bar=0 test.txt file
$ sed -ir 's/(foo|bar)=0//g' /var/tmp/test.txt
$ egrep "(foo|bar)=0" /var/tmp/test.txt
This is example output of the test.txt file foo=0
This is another example output of the bar=0 test.txt file
$
```

Trying with perl the substitute works:

```
$ egrep "(foo|bar)=0" /var/tmp/test.txt
This is example output of the test.txt file foo=0
This is another example output of the bar=0 test.txt file
$ perl -ne 's/(foo|bar)=0//g;print;' -i /var/tmp/test.txt
$ egrep "(foo|bar)=0" /var/tmp/test.txt
$
```

Is there a way to make sed accomplish what perl's doing here?  Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a problem on the order of the arguments you provide to `sed`. Say `sed -r -i` and you will see it working.

When you say `sed -ir` you are setting in-place editing but NOT `-r` mode. Why? Because `-r` is understood as the parameter for `-i`, so that you end up having a `file` + `r` backup.

---

Full test:

```
$ sed -ir 's/(foo|bar)=0//g' file
```

`file` and `filer` are equal!

```
$ cat file
This is example output of the test.txt file foo=0
This is filenother example output of the bar=0 test.txt file
$ cat filer
This is example output of the test.txt file foo=0
This is filenother example output of the bar=0 test.txt file
```

Let's separate the parameters:

```
$ sed -i -r 's/(foo|bar)=0//g' file
```

Now it is fine, `file` doesn't have this content any more:

```
$ cat file                         
This is example output of the test.txt file 
This is filenother example output of the  test.txt file
```

Comment: Same as `perl -in -e '...'`, for example.